# Trusted Subsystem Pattern and Modern Websites

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security

Iam new in a company which works with the trusted subsystem pattern (at least I think, thats it), ASP.NET Applications and Webservices.

The workflow is like this:

```
Client -> Website -> DMZ(Service -> DMZ(Database))
```

In this case you have a two layer security system. Developing this is really a mess, because all database operations are linked to the webservice. And this results in a single service file, without encapsulation of different request purposes. Also you have to rebuild every sql feature for ordering, filtering and so on. You can't use any ORM or you have to rebuild your models in own service models.

My Question is: Is it really neccessary or safer to use this pattern? I am totally new to this , have only worked with websites accessing the databse directly until now.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use any ORM or you have to rebuild your models in own service models.

That is a problem that has been solved. Look at T4 templates and AutoMapper.

You really just *can't* expose a database over the web. Managing row or table level security for many web users where you have to give each such user a *database* account is undoable.